# UIMA/dkpro: Get type of conjunction

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, uima, dkpro-core

I am using UIMA in combination with UIMAfit and dkpro and the StanfordParser to parse english sentences.

I can build dependency trees without any problem. For "and"/"or" conjunctions, I get a Annotation with class `CONJ`, which is a subclass of `Dependency`. As of now, I did not find out, how to check if the found conjunction is an "AND" or an "OR" conjunction.

Does anybody know how to solve this? I saw examples where the dependencies "conj_and" and "conj_or" are displayed, but I dont see where they come from.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf

Thanks in advance

Some code for visualization:

```
// CONJ a;
// StringBuilder sb
Token dependent = a.getDependent();
Token governor = a.getGovernor();

sb.append("Dependent: ");
sb.append(dependent);
sb.append(", ");

sb.append("Governor: ");
sb.append(governor);

// How to check type conj_and/conj_or?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to get the label of the dependency relation is called

```
getDependencyType()
```

Mind that the `conj_or` is a "collapsed dependency". If you want to get these, you have to explicitly set the dependency mode when invoking the DKPro Core StanfordParser component, e.g. using `COLLAPSED` or maybe `CC_PROPAGATED`:

```
AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(StanfordParser.class,
  StanfordParser.PARAM_MODE, StanfordParser.DependenciesMode.COLLAPSED)
```

The default setting for this parameter is `TREE`.

See also:

- [DKPro Core Stanford.Parser.DEpendenciesMode Javadoc](http://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.7.0/apidocs/index.html?de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/stanfordnlp/StanfordParser.DependenciesMode.html)
- [Stanford CoreNLP GrammaticalStructure Javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/index.html?edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalStructure.html)

*Disclosure: I am a member of the DKPro Core team*.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for!